# How to configure useful information in 'Alert Description' in SCE

Tags: system-center-essentials

Firstly.  I want to meet the person or team who came up with the way SCE works, because they can't possibly be sane.

Secondly.  I am trying to configure my low disk space email alert to actually show me what disk is low, and how low it is.   I am in the alert description edit box.  I have managed to insert the computer's network name, and its ip address.  But if I try to add data it just inserts this line

```
$Data/Context/[PropertyName]$
```

and then tells me to replace [PropertyName] with the name of the property of the data item.

How do I find out the property names of the data items I'm trying to look at?

And a secondary question:  Is it possible to insert line breaks into this alert description? (to make it more readable)  If I press enter or shift-enter it just submits the changes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found the following page - http://blogs.technet.com/b/kevinholman/archive/2007/12/12/adding-custom-information-to-alert-descriptions-and-notifications.aspx which gives a list of values.

Through trial and error I determined that the following are the values I was looking for

[image: Values]